# MySQL error 1064 - the right syntax?

Tags: mysql, ssh, amazon-web-services, syntax-error

I am very new to MySQL so before you decide to downvote this please just add a comment and I will delete the post. I am following a tutorial on android-hive, http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/, that uses MySQL as a database for holding user information. I set up MySQL on an AWS EC2 Linux instance, along with apache tomcat etc. etc. The tutorial says:

```
Open your mysql console or phpmyadmin and run following query to create database 
and users table:

create database android_api /** Creating Database **/

use android_api /** Selecting Database **/

create table users(
uid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
name varchar(50) not null,
email varchar(100) not null unique,
encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
salt varchar(10) not null,
created_at datetime,
updated_at datetime null
); /** Creating Users Table **/
```

I connect to my Linux instance via SSH and start MySQL and run the query that is stated in the tutorial. I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'use android_api
create table users(
uid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
' at line 3
```

I really have no idea how to solve this and I appreciate any help given, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you have missed the statement separator. try and use ";" at the end of each query.

Comment: This is close enough. I was simply entering the query incorrectly... a very stupid beginners mistake. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is

```
use android_api //this one is correct
```

but in error message the quote is

```
uses android_api
```

so it looks like this code is not exactly same that You have problem with.

Comment: Yes I noticed that and ran it again...Here is the new error message:
 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'use android_api
create table users(
   uid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
 ' at line 3

Comment: use android_api and create table... are 2 separate queries if You try to call them one without proper separator You get error

Answer (score 1):

If anyone encounters this in the future. The solution is to use the create database query first, then after creation of the database use the "use" query and the create table query together.

Comment: The accepted answer already pointed out that the issue was a typographical error.

Comment: how so? You can submit multiple statements in a single action `;` is used to define the end of one statement, and the start of the next. This is databasing 101

Comment: depending on phpmyadmin version maybe. Mine didn't work as a single statement. Had to do it like i described.

Answer (score -1):

there is a syntex mistake use ";" after second statement like
use android_api;
it worked for me :-)

Comment: Your answer is likely correct, but it doesn't build on to the already existing answers present here.